# ServiceStack .NET Silverlight wrong result

Tags: servicestack

I'm tring to set up a sample demo running ServiceStack with Silverlight. I've read [this article](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SilverlightServiceClient)

and I've successfully been able to invoke the method on server...

Currently my demo app is made of

- Name.Web (Service and Silverlight hoster)
- Name.Web.DTO contains request/response classes
- Name.Silverlight (main SL application)
- Name.Silverlight.DTO contains a copy (Add as Link in VS) of the class
  in Name.Web.DTO

My sevice class is

```
public class TestService : Service
{
    public object  Any (TestRequest request)
    {
        var lst = new List<TestResponse>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var item = new TestResponse { ID = i, Descrizione = string.Format("Descr_{0}", i) };

            lst.Add(item);
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

And the response/request are really simple

```
[Route("/test")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<IList<TestResponse>>
{
}

[DataContract]
public class TestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
}
```

On silverlight part in the serviceClient_Completed I've 20 items (as service produce) but all with ID=0,Descrizione=string.Empty

What can be the reason of this? I've also tried looking with FireBug/Fiddler but I don't see anything (maybe since I'm on localhost?) or that's due to the fact serviceClient is made via ClientHttp?

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri(_baseUri + uri));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've seend that if I use descrizione and id instead of Descrizione and ID it takes the values... what can be the reason of that?Thanks

Comment: I've spotted the problem it was ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true; ...setting it to false works....